# Django: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: django, attributeerror

I am trying to create a chat app and got stuck with this error.
I am getting this error though I'm logged in as a superuser.

My models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username

    def last_10_messages():
        return Message.objects.order_by('-timestamp').all()[:10]
```

Where I try to access it:

```
for message in messages:
            print("message printing")
            result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
```

then

```
def message_to_json(self, message):
        print("message.id=",message.id)
        print(message.author.username)
        return {
            'id': message.id,
            'author': message.author.username,
            'content': message.content,
            'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
        }
```

When i print the length of the object i notice it says 2..idk why coz i haven't added any messages yet.
As the loop goes twice i noticed that the username got printed the first time but raised an error for the second loop(though idk why it loops coz i dont even have messages to load yet)
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v28eD.png)

The error also appears to be in the return function in my models class [as in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdODR.png)

I've read other posts but their errors were different...
Would be really grateful if sum1 cud help out!!
or how do i define and access author variables the correct way

Comment: The `.author` is `None`, it does not matter if you are logged in or not, you apparently did not save the `author` to refer to a `User` object.

Comment: message.author can be null, you are not handling this case when accessing message.author.username

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i refer the author to User in the class and User=get_user_model()

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem know of any way I can solve it?..

Answer (score 3):

If you allow the `author` to not be set then you need to make sure it has been set before you try to use it.

Be a little defensive like this;

```
class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.author:
            return "Anonymous"
        return self.author.username

    def last_10_messages():
        return Message.objects.order_by('-timestamp').all()[:10]
```

```
    def message_to_json(self, message):
        if message.author:
            author = message.author.username
        else:
            author = "Anonymous"

        return {
            'id': message.id,
            'author': author,
            'content': message.content,
            'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
        }
```

Comment: Thx but it Didnt work for me... the same error pops up and the "if not self.author" statement doesnt even get executed....

Comment: i made some changes n tried so it works..but i need to add this if condition everywhere else i wanna use the username

Comment: Yes, of course. If you want to access an attribute of something, you need to ensure it exists everywhere you want to use it. Making it a property of your model would make this much easier and avoid the repetition of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have more the one message even if you said you did not create any. At least you must have created one with the username aysha. The message with the `id=1` seems to have no user attached ... so you get the error when trying to access `message.author.username`.

To add the `if not self.author` in the `__str__` of `Message` does not change anything as you access or print `message.author.username` and not message. It would help if you `print(message)` and message has no author.